# Listing all the diferent strings from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

i'm still a newbie with R and I can't figure this out. I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Age         State     Diagnosis
 12         Texas   Lung Cancer
 67    California  Colon Cancer
 45       Wyoming   Lung Cancer
 36      New Mex.      Leukemia
 58       Arizona  Colon Cancer
 35      Colorado      Leukemia
```

I need a program that somehow prints or adds into another dataframe all the different strings that are located in each column. So I can Know all the "types". For example, in the case of the column "diagnosis", the program should create a dataframe with only "Lung cancer, colon cancer and leukemia" since there are only those 3 types, even though they are repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unique`.

Assuming you have a dataframe `data` with all the information, you can use the function `unique()` to list all the occurences, removing repetitions:

```
types <- unique(data$diagnosis)
```

Comment: Thanks! this was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

you can do the following to get the data

```
AllDiagnosis <- unique(data$Diagnosis)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option with `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  distinct(diagnosis) %>%
  pull(diagnosis)
```